# Updating Calendar.SECOND in while loop

Tags: java, static, while-loop, calendar

My objective is to run a program in java that performs a list of code at a certain time each day.

I am aware of the TimerTask and Timer utilities but there is a reason to not using those. 
Much of my code is run under a while loop with the condition that the thread is still alive.

Some declarations:

```
static int theHour;
static int theMinute;
static int theSecond;
```

The beginning of my while loop:

```
while (this.threadAlive)
{
   System.out.println("START thread");
   theHour = theTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   theMinute = theTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   theSecond = theTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   System.out.println("the second is: " + theSecond);
   //...
   //...
   //...
   try
   {
      if (theHour == 12 && theMinute == 39 && (theSecond >= 0 || theSecond < 10)  )
      {
         System.out.println("In the loop");
         if (super.connectToDevice())
         {
            // Send the data command to the device
            //out.println(COMMAND_GP);
            System.out.println("Simulation of midnight is successful");

            // Read and store the data returned from the device
            String data = in.readLine();

            data = "test gps data";
            // Send the data off to be processed 
            sendDataForProcessing(data);

            // Disconnect from the device 
            super.disconnectFromDevice();


         }

      }

      //Catch any exceptions here
}
```

The result in the console after about 10 seconds of runtime:

```
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
START thread
the second is: 46
```

The result I get for `theSecond` is correct but it never updates after going through the loop again. My declarations are defined globally in the class and I have tried declaring them just as `int` but that did not make a difference. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is running and printing it out much faster than the system clock is updating

Comment: That would be true if the while loop was as simple as the print statements. The list of code I mention refers to connecting to a microcontroller, grabbing data, disconnecting, sleeping and then resuming again

Comment: Sounds pretty complicated

Comment: I will post some more code to give a better picture

Comment: Where is `theTime` set, and how is it updated in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will solve your problem:

Try adding this at the start of your loop:

```
Calendar theTime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that your **theSecond** variable is declared as **static**.  This means that once you set the value once, it cannot be changed.

Take out the "static" and you'll be good to go.

EDIT: I now see you've mentioned that you've tried w/o the static.  I'm now wondering if somehow you're running a previously-compiled version of the code that is still treating it as static?  I see no other reason this would be an issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing that Juan. I can't see how it would try to run a previously-compiled version. I am working in Eclipse and have saved and compiled the program before running.

Comment: Can you try doing the following:  System.out.println(theTime.get(Calendar.SECOND)); (instead of printing "theSecond") and in this case does it still print the same value?

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with "once you set the value once, it cannot be changed".

Comment: That was an interesting suggestion but yes, it does still print the same value when I tried that.

Comment: Now we know it does not involve your variable.  Try adding this at the start of your loop: 

Calendar theTime = Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: Juan you just figured it out man. I had `Calendar theTime = Calendar.getInstance()` before my while loop. Post that comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help.